# How to add dynamically html table data in mysql database using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have following code, with java script code for add dynamically rows to table and add values as table data,
but i'm unable to add data into a database. It contains with add button function.Right now the code does not insert data to the database. So,i need to add dynamically html data into mysql database with using PHP code

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <SCRIPT language="javascript">
   function addRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   var element1 = document.createElement("input");
   element1.type = "text";
   element1.name="txtbox[]";
   cell1.appendChild(element1);

       var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.name="txtbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);

           var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.name="txtbox[]";
        cell1.appendChild(element1);



    }


     </script>
     </head>
     <div id="table_wrapper">
     <table class="meta">
      <tr id="noExl"
            <th><span contenteditable>Invoice #</span></th>
            <td><span contenteditable>101138</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="noExl">
                <th><span contenteditable>Date</span></th>
                <td><span contenteditable>January 1, 2012</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="noExl">
                <th><span contenteditable>Amount Due</span></th>
                <td><span id="prefix" contenteditable>Rs</span>
            <span>600.00</span></td>
            </tr>
           </table>
          <table class="inventory" id="dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr id="noExl">
                    <th><span contenteditable>Item</span></th>
                    <th><span contenteditable>Description</span></th>

                    <th><span contenteditable>Amount</span></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr id="noExl">
                    <td><a class="cut">-</a><span contenteditable>Front End 
                     Consultation</span></td>
                    <td><span contenteditable>Experience Review</span></td>

                    <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" 
                    id="qty1"/></td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>


            <tbody>

            </tbody>

        </table>
          <INPUT type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing that you have ready to post data in database

1. Grab you all values in a java script function
2. Post these values using ajax

I am attaching a sample ajax method, you can modify it as per own requirements

```js
//call to remote update function
update_table(var1,var2);

//method definition
function update_table(var1,var2){
var action_post_data='id='+var1+'&total'+var2;
 jQuery.ajax({
             url: 'update/table',
             type: 'POST',
             data: action_post_data,
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (data) {
             //do something
                     }
                 },
                error: function () {
                    
                      //do something
                }
            }
```